# Javascript 'Print' button straight to 'Save as PDF'

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, printing

I want to implement a button that will allow users to save a pdf copy of an html page. I know they can go through the 'print' interface, and select the 'save as pdf' option, but I'd rather have my button automatically select that option so that it automatically selects the option 'save as pdf' (or better yet, goes straight to the pdf download).

Is there a way to do this in javascript?

Answer (score 8):

The "Save to PDF" button in the print dialog doesn't exist in Windows afaik.
Anyway, there's no way you can do this with Javascript.

If you really want to give your visitors a PDF download of your page, you need to render that PDF on the server side and link the button to the PDF file.

Comment: this is inherently untrue. The most prominent tool for generating PDF's from client is jsPDF. There are others.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich as far as I can see the first version of jsPDF was released Feb 2014.  6 months after my reply.

Comment: Actually, jsPDF was first beta-d in 2009 and production released in 2010. Since then multiple plug-ins and js packages make your answer either wrong or antiquated. Seems time to revise or delete.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just link the button to a script that converts the page to a PDF. You can either use your own server script to convert the page to PDF or use a save as PDF link to a service like [HTM2PDF](http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk).

It's not clear in both cases why you would need to utilize JavaScript at all. But if you're really keen on using JavaScript I believe there's something like a 'headless webkit' in JavaScript by the  name of [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Comment: PhantomJS is a great tool for getting html source, but packages like jsPDF make the OP's intention possible. Open Source packages constantly improve and commercial packages are very good. As the post has been closed, you would be very helpful in revising your answer. For now this post is misleading to any who come here.